# Cómo mostrar productos del mismo proveedor de una tabla

Tags: mysql, sql

Soy nuevo, Tengo una tabla donde quiero mostrar en una columna (`vProducto`) los productos del mismo Proveedor. Tengo este código No funciona, me da error ¡Cualquier ayuda por favor!

```
SELECT vProducto case when vProveedor= Telefonica  AS tot 
FROM mod_productos 
WHERE eCodigoProdId = eCodigoProdId
```

Me muestra este error:

> (You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'case when vProveedor= Telefonica AS tot FROM mod_productos WHERE
>   `eCodigoProdId' at line 1)

De antemano GRACIAS !

Comment: La consulta no puede funcionar así. Si quieres los productos de `Telefónica` debes ponerlo en un `WHERE`. Tampoco se entiende que tabla es `mbpm`... Si hay varias tablas debes unirlas mediante un `JOIN`. Debes dar más detalles si quieres que se te ayude, indicando cuáles son tus tablas y como se relacionan entre sí.

Comment: Gracias @A. Cedano, Estoy en proceso de aprender comunicarme funciona aqui. 
Solo es mostrar en una columna los nombres de productos del proveedor Telefonica,  y se supone ya puse el WHERE (WHERE eCodigoProdId = mbpm.eCodigoProdId) y el mbpm es solo indicativo de la columna a usar pero se puede quitar no importa. EL caso es que aun con el WHERE me muestra el error.

Comment: Use este Query  y ahora me da otro error...SELECT vProducto FROM mod_productos WHERE vProducto IN (SELECT vProducto FROM mod_productos  WHERE vProveedor="Telefonica")

Error 
Error Number: 1242
Subquery returns more than 1 row

Comment: mbmp es otra tabla? deberías agregar la estructura de las 2 tablas involucradas para poder ayudarte

Comment: Gracias @Alfredo , no es tra tabla, solo complemento de el nombre de la columna donde se mostrara el resultado. Se lo puedo quitar sin problema.

Comment: y no te sirve solo hacer SELECT vProducto FROM mod_productos WHERE vPorveedor = 'Telefonica';  @MuhvaPlay así te debería funcionar si solo quieres los datos de telefonica no veo necesario el case que de todos modos esta incompleta la sentencia

Comment: Amigo @Alfredo me regresa este erro: Subquery returns more than 1 row y en muchisimas busquedas de soluciones en gogole no encuentro como slucionarlo

Comment: al final prueba con un limit 1; justo al final de tu consulta @MuhvaPlay

Comment: SI FUNCIONA ! solo que solo me muestra un solo producto, Muchas gracias, ahora la tarea es ver como muestre todos los productos del mismo proveedor.

Comment: Si tu tabla se llama `mod_productos` y tienes dos columnas `vProducto` y `vProveedor` y quieres obtener todos los productos del proveedor `Telefónoca` lo único que tienes que hacer es: `SELECT vProducto FROM mod_productos WHERE vProveedor='Telefónica'` Te traerá todos los productos de ese proveedor si el contexto es el que te comento. Si es otro contexto entonces debes decir cuál es para poder ayudarte. Cuando entiendas como funciona entonces considera mejorar la estructura creando una tabla proveedores como ya se te ha dicho y relacionando por el ID.

Answer (score 0):

Está un poco confusa tu pregunta, por mas que la leo no logro entenderla, pero si quieres mostrar todos los productos del mismo proveedor es necesario saber si los proveedores están en una tabla proveedores.

Yo haría lo siguiente, no se si es tu estructura.

- Creo la tabla producto y a esa tabla le agrego un idProveedores.
- Creo la tabla proveedores (idProvee)

Luego hago la consulta así:

SELECT vProducto
FROM mod_productos
INNER JOIN TProveedores
ON idProveedores = idProvee
ORDER BY idProveedores

Espero y te ayude.

Saludos

Comment: pero si pregunta en el título dice que la misma tabla

Comment: El vProducto y el VProveedor estan en la misma tabla (mod_productos)

Comment: Okay gracias Alfredo, no está bien su estructura, lo que le recomiendo es que lo haga agregando otra tabla. Lo que el quiere es agrupar los del mismo proveedor, lo que le recomiendo es que use la opción ORDER BY de MySQL para que lo organice por proveedor, ahora bien si el quiere un numero, pues que use la funcion count() para que le haga un conteo y le de el total. Creo que a su pregunta está poco entendible entonces.

Comment: @MuhvaPlay lo tuyo ya te entendí, está fácil, has esto: "SELECT count(*) AS tot, vProducto FROM mod_productos GROUP BY eCodigoProdId" Eso debe ayudarte... Avísame cualquier cosa.

Comment: Me muestra este Error: Operand should contain 1 column(s)
Sin embargo necesito me muestre los productos del mismo proveedor, por favor si puedes ayudarme, Mil gracias por tu aporte de cualquier manera !

Comment: Que estas utilizando, MySQL o SQL Server?

Comment: Utilizando Mysql

Comment: Okay, entiendo, yo he probado eso antes de enviartelo y me aseguré de que funciona. Quítale el AS tot del SELECT a ver que te dice.

Comment: Le quite el AS tot y me marca error: Operand should contain 1 column(s)
Trate de ponerle este WHERE vProveedor = eCodigoProdId Me marac mismo error

Comment: Debes tratar de ir eliminando cosas, por ejemplo vas bien, ahora quitale el count(*) a ver si funciona algo y no te da error, sin embargo no te dará el resultado que espera pero te ayudará a saber que ahí esta el problema. Si te funciona, entonces debes verificar cual es la versión del MySQL que estás ejecutando y ver en la documentación si han removido esa funcion en esa versión y cual es la alternativa.

Comment: @gbelen ,Gracias por tus comentarios, son motivantes !
SELECT vProducto FROM `mod_productos` WHERE `eCodigoProdId` = `mbpm`.`eCodigoProdId`
he usado este codigo pero me regresa todos los prductos, seguire buscando y luego pondre que codigo me funciono. Gracias !